# Configure PolyORB fails on Linux with GNAT 2019 public version for Linux 64 bit

Tags: linux, configuration, ada, gnat

The configure script checks that the compiler can build c programs and fails saying the compiler for c cannot build executables. (checking whether the C compiler works... no)

doing the command gcc x.c gives "gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory"

uname -a for my system says: x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

My guess is that this version of GNAT was not configured correctly for c programs. Next thing to try is an older version of GNAT

Answer (score 0):

The [`INSTALL`](https://github.com/AdaCore/PolyORB/blob/master/INSTALL) file should give some additional info (in particular the last line, in case you have multiple versions of GNAT installed). Using GNAT CE 2019 installed on Debian 10 (Buster):

```
$ uname -a
Linux debian 4.19.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u1 (2019-09-20) x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ which gcc
/opt/GNAT/2019/bin/gcc

$ sudo apt-get install autoconf automake libtool
[...]

$ git clone https://github.com/AdaCore/PolyORB.git
[...]

$ cd PolyORB
$ support/reconfig
Running aclocal (GNU automake) 1.16.1
Running autoheader (GNU Autoconf) 2.69
Running autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.69
Generating IDL tree accessors
splitting nodes.ada into:
   idl_fe-tree.ads
   idl_fe-tree.adb
Doing the necessary date modifications

$ ./configure
[...]
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
[...]

$ make
[...]
```